# This socket has been ended by the other party] code: 'EPIPE'

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg, node-postgres

I'm receiving this error after some actions, for example, in ~10 seconds after successful insert:

```
Error: This socket has been ended by the other party] code: 'EPIPE'
```

Means, first time i'm inserting it fine, but when i'm attempting to do insert something else, or retrieve data or ... etc - i'm getting this error.
It doesn't happen after idle. Only after some actions. Some times after retrieval and always after insert.
Insert query example:

```
var query = "insert into public.comment (text,owner,owner_name,resource_type, resource_id,parent) values ('some text','40c28840-4241-4b7a-b339-29d9759693eb','UserName','note','33695e8b-5cff-42a1-9c64-7c0a3cd0f411','8a416406-c848-46e0-ac14-6aa6bcdb5044') returning owner,owner_name,text,parent,created,id"

    client.query(query, function(err, result) {
      done();
      if (err) {
        socket.emit('userError', 0) // unknownError
        return console.error('ERROR '+query, err);
      }
      console.log(result)
    });
```

here is the same query, i've formatted it a bit to make it easier to read:

```
insert into public.comment (
text,
owner,
owner_name,
resource_type, 
resource_id,
parent
) 
values (
'some text',
'40c28840-4241-4b7a-b339-29d9759693eb',
'UserName',
'note',
'33695e8b-5cff-42a1-9c64-7c0a3cd0f411',
'8a416406-c848-46e0-ac14-6aa6bcdb5044'
) returning owner,owner_name,text,parent,created,id
```